# Is it a good RESTFUL API having different response format in same status code?

Tags: rest

Is front-end supposed to handle response with different json format under the same status code?

Or it's back-end's job to separate them into different status code?

I'm asking this because I'm now provided with a restful api which have different json response under status code 200.

e.g.

First one:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "msg": "have no user data",
    "inputs": {
        "id": "thisisafaketestid"
    }
}
```

Second one:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "somename",
        "email": "someEmail@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

And the status code of both requests are 200.

Comment: It's really difficult as an outside developer to program against an API which body can change depending on something out of hand of the caller. So I would not change those based on the same code. Instead use different status codes and/or different endpoints if you want different replies.

Comment: There isn't any way to objectively answer this: whether it is a "good" design is pure opinion; and whether it is "RESTful" is hard to judge because REST is not a concrete standard, just a set of principles. If it's an API you've been given, rather than one you're writing, the question is kind of pointless anyway - the more interesting question is "how should I handle this in my client code", but we can't answer that without knowing what technologies you're using on the client.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, and sorry for the late response. I've been thinking a lot and decide to be an engineer who solve the problem by actually solving the problem. So I will stop discussing the reasonableness and instead focus on my work handling the api response. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

That first response seems like it should have a different status code. If you are looking up a specific user in this case and it is not found the statuscode should probably be 404.

Regardless, the message structure should not be different.

Answer (score 0):

Status codes, like [200 OK](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.3.1), are metadata in the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain.  You asked the server for a current representation of the resource, the server is sending back to you a current representation of the resource.  200 OK is completely appropriate.

Imagine, for example, a plain old boring web server.  You ask for a copy of `/example.json`, the server looks on disk, finds that file, and sends it back to you.  What's the right status code to use?  200 OK.  Do the semantics of the *contents* of the document change that answer?  No.

---

It may or may not be good resource design - ie, is this the kind of document schema that makes for a good API experience?

There are cases where it does make a lot of sense: the report that describes the outcome of job-123 might indicate the job failed; the report that describes the status of server-456 might indicate that the server is unhealthy.

A document that tells us our domain process is not on the happy-path might be sharing very different information, with different fields.

The design you demonstrate here might be "fine", or might be the best available compromise.

And yes, when these kinds of designs are appropriate, the client has to parse the document to determine the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

The response when calling the API haves http status code: 200, 403, 404, 500...
Usually we let the server handle the default, but sometimes we will control them (With .net is StatusCode).

1. Is front-end supposed to handle response with different json format under the same status code?

- Yes
  Please see code with jquery:

  ```js
       $.ajax({
          type: type,
          url: url,    
          dataType: 'json',
          data: params,
          success: function (data) {
                  if(data.status == 200){ //this is http status code
                      // success call
                      if (data.return.status == 'error1'){ //this is your logic error
                        your code here
                      }
                  }
          },
          error: function (data) {
                   if (data.status == 401) { // this is http status code
                    // Unaurhorized
          }
          })
  ```

2. Or it's back-end's job to separate them into different status code?
   Yes (as explained above)
   However in case you want to return a logical error you should do the same as your code above. That is to use the status field to return the error code. The return can be handled as follows:

```py
        // handle http status code if needed. I usually let the server handle this by default, with return codes of 200, 404, 500..
        your code here
        // handle logic error
        if (error1) { status = "error1"} else if (error2) { status = "error2"} 
        your code here
        // execute your logic
        your code here
```